# How to write following javascript in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea about Angular.js. But want I want to do is 
this

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function showAndroidToast(toast) {
         Android.showToast(toast);
       }
    </script>
    </head>
```

and this

```
<body>
     <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
</body>
```

any idea?

Comment: Refer Angular docs. just these Angular code will not teach you Angular.

Comment: Thanks, but I have not much time for that. And I have no any javascript knowledge.

Comment: Any how you need to learn Angular. Than only you will understood.

Answer (score 2):

Here is angular js code.

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {

             $scope.showAndroidToast = function(toast) {
                    //write your code here to perform some action on calling this function
                    //Android.showToast(toast);
                    alert(toast);
                    console.log(toast);
                  }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
 <input type="button" value="Say hello" ng-click="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.., web guy said we need angular 2. Gonna fix the question.

Comment: Ok But you asked angular 1 code before editing the question. so this answer is for angular 1. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should go through docs first of angular :

Its so simple as below :

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  

  $scope.showAndroidToast = function(toast) {
       Android.showToast(toast); // Android should be inject as an dependency otherwise it would be undefined.

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="button" value="Say hello" ng-click="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

</body>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.., web guy said we need angular 2. Gonna fix the question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a simple example for you. I was missing the `Android` class, so I tested it using the `alert()` function.

**AngularJS 2**

- [Plunkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kdPUvrUWPogxslxOeH1s?p=preview)

**Guidelines**

- [AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)
- [File-closure and Strict mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/javascript/javascript-coding-standards#strict)

**Angular Components**

- [ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)
- [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)
- [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  function exampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.showAndroidToast = showAndroidToast;
    
    function showAndroidToast(message) {
      alert(message); // replace this with your toast message
    }
  }
  
  var app = angular.module("exampleApp", []);
  
  app.controller("exampleController", exampleController);
  
})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="exampleController as vm">
  <input type="button" value="Say hello" ng-click="vm.showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great.., I'm gonna ask the web developer to fix the code. :D

Comment: I'm so sorry.., web guy said we need angular 2. Gonna fix the question.

Comment: @CristyYG I've created the example for AngularJS 2 https://plnkr.co/edit/kdPUvrUWPogxslxOeH1s?p=preview